# Why doesnt work my OpenCL function if i use other GPU?

Tags: c#, arrays, opencl

I am using [Cloo](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cloo.clSharp/) to concat big arrays using my GPU, all works fine at my first PC (which have an AMD RX 570) but at the second one (Nvidia 920m) my function does nothing and my application crash because my copied array was filled by 0s.

This is my function (I added prinf to check if my program was actually using it):

```cs
kernel void ArrayCopy(global uchar* bufferIn, int inOffset, 
                      global uchar* bufferOut, int outOffset) 
{
    int index = get_global_id(0);
    bufferOut[index + outOffset] = bufferIn[index + inOffset];
    printf("It works!");
}
```

I dont know why `Cloo` doesn't give me an exception, warning or anything else.

I minned some data about my graphics card while I was debugging my application:

- [RX 570](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOZbw.png)
- [920m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gperH.png)

Thanks for all and sorry for my bad english.

**EDIT:**

I have created a program who sends images over an `UDP socket`, those images can reach **more than 200KB** so I should send them in more than one packet and rebuild them in the same order at my client application.

Since I was using `sockets` those arrays will be byte arrays (`byte[]`) which [equivalent in OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/scalarDataTypes.html) is `uchar*`.

Nodaways I am using [`Sytem.Array.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-5.0) to rebuild those images, which is very slow due those arrays sizes. Thus I have written a function using `Cloo` which takes 5 arguments (like `System.Array.Copy`):

- **bufferIn** (Source array)
- **inOffset** (Source index to start reading values)
- **bufferOut** (Destination array)
- **outOffset** (Destination index to start setting values)
- **lenght** (Number of elements to copy).

```cs
public void GPUCopy(byte[] bufferIn, int inOffset, byte[] bufferOut, int outOffset, int lenght)
{
    ComputeBuffer<byte> originBuffer, destBuffer;

    originBuffer = new ComputeBuffer<byte>(context,
        ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadOnly | ComputeMemoryFlags.UseHostPointer, bufferIn);
    destBuffer = new ComputeBuffer<byte>(context,
        ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadOnly | ComputeMemoryFlags.UseHostPointer, bufferOut);

    kernel.SetMemoryArgument(0, originBuffer);
    kernel.SetValueArgument(1, inOffset);
    kernel.SetMemoryArgument(2, destBuffer);
    kernel.SetValueArgument(3, outOffset);

    queue.Execute(kernel, new long[] { 0 }, new long[] { lenght }, null, new ComputeEventList());
    queue.Finish();
}
```

As I said before this works fine with my **RX 570** and gives me no error at my **920m**.

Full class source code here:

```cs
class GPU
{
    private ComputeCommandQueue queue;
    private ComputeContext context;
    private ComputeKernel kernel;

    private string ArrayCopy
    {
        get
        {
            return @"
                    kernel void ArrayCopy(global uchar* bufferIn, int inOffset, global uchar* bufferOut, int outOffset) 
                    {
                          int index = get_global_id(0);
                          bufferOut[index + outOffset] = bufferIn[index + inOffset];
                    }";
        }
    }

    public GPU()
    {
        context = new ComputeContext(ComputeDeviceTypes.Gpu, new ComputeContextPropertyList(ComputePlatform.Platforms[0]), null, IntPtr.Zero);
        queue = new ComputeCommandQueue(context, context.Devices[0], ComputeCommandQueueFlags.None);
        var program = new ComputeProgram(context, ArrayCopy);
        program.Build(null, null, null, IntPtr.Zero);

        kernel = program.CreateKernel("ArrayCopy");
    }

    public void GPUCopy(byte[] bufferIn, int inOffset, byte[] bufferOut, int outOffset, int lenght)
    {
        ComputeBuffer<byte> originBuffer, destBuffer;

        originBuffer = new ComputeBuffer<byte>(context,
            ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadOnly | ComputeMemoryFlags.UseHostPointer, bufferIn);
        destBuffer = new ComputeBuffer<byte>(context,
            ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadOnly | ComputeMemoryFlags.UseHostPointer, bufferOut);

        kernel.SetMemoryArgument(0, originBuffer);
        kernel.SetValueArgument(1, inOffset);
        kernel.SetMemoryArgument(2, destBuffer);
        kernel.SetValueArgument(3, outOffset);

        queue.Execute(kernel, new long[] { 0 }, new long[] { lenght }, null, new ComputeEventList());
        queue.Finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if later but I don't think nvidia supports `printf` in opencl 1.2 -  remove it and do retest.

Comment: @doqtor My first attempt was without printf, nothing changes.

Comment: Then more information is needed, like what are in and out offset values, how big are buffers - in general the host part of your code.

Comment: I'd expect some errors to be returned on the host side. Are you sure you're checking these sufficiently?

Comment: Incidentally, for copying buffer subranges, you should probably be using [`clEnqueueCopyBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueCopyBuffer.html) which uses the device's DMA engine(s) if available, rather than a custom kernel.

Comment: Sorry. i was at class and i did not notice thoses comments. I added more information.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided very little information in your question, but I can think of a few things you need to check or try, and comments are somewhat awkward for this, so here's an "answer":

- What version of OpenCL does your context comply with? In OpenCL 1.0, bytewise addressing is not built-in, and you are copying one byte (`uchar`) at a time. So if your context is an OpenCL 1.0 context, check that your device supports the [`cl_khr_byte_addressable_store` extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_byte_addressable_store.html) and enable it in your kernel. (In OpenCL 1.1 and newer, you do not need to do this.)
- If the above is not the cause for your issues, I'd expect some errors to be returned on the host side. Are you sure you're checking these sufficiently? I'm not familiar with the cloo wrapper and there doesn't seem to be any documentation(?) but in plain OpenCL, almost every host function returns a result code of some kind, and if you don't check and handle this, it typically results in the sort of behaviour you're seeing.
- If your kernel really is as you have posted, and this is not just a reduced example: For copying buffer subranges, you should probably be using [`clEnqueueCopyBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueCopyBuffer.html), which uses the device's DMA engine(s) if available, rather than a custom kernel. I would be very surprised if this was slower in any OpenCL implementations, and it will be faster in some.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried your first solution but it didnt works. How can I implement `clEnqueueCopyBuffer`? and which wrapper do you recommend?. I was using `Cloo` beause it was the first wrapper i found.

Comment: @AdriánFernández I can't recommend one for C#/.NET as that's not a runtime I typically use, sorry.